# unable to reset the password using System.ResetPassword()

Tags: apex, lightning, reset-password

I'm trying to reset the password for the logged-in user and I'm getting this error

> INVALID_SESSION_ID: This session is not valid for use with the API

```
public class apexclass1 {
   @AuraEnabled
   public static void resetUserPassword() {
        List<User> commUserList = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Id = '005xx000001Sv7I' LIMIT 1];
        ResetPasswordResult rpr = System.resetPassword(commUserList.Id, true);
         System.debug('/// ' + rpr.getPassword());
    }
}
```

Lightning Component

```
<aura:component controller="apexclass1" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:appHostable">
<lightning:button label="Reset Password" onclick="{!c.reset}" />
</aura:component>
```

Controller:

```
({
reset : function(component, event, helper) {
console.log('zzz ' + 'Invoked resetUserPassword');
var action = component.get("c.resetUserPassword");
action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
var state = response.getState();
if (state === "SUCCESS") {
console.log('SUCCESS');
} else if (state === "ERROR") {
console.log('ERROR');
}
});
$A.enqueueAction(action);
},
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A00000031PwQAI&title=unable-to-reset-the-password-using-system-resetpassword-with-aura-session

Seems to be a known issue. Check to see if your instance is still listed as one that it is not fixed for.